# Wait for Input in User Control

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to implement a customized exit prompt in my WinForms. (I should not be using DialogBox)

I have a User Control Object placed in my main form that is invisible and disabled by default. Clicking in a certain button I have placed on the form shows and enables the object, disabling everything in my form except the User Control.

```
private void btn_close_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        prompt1.Visible = true;
        prompt1.Enabled = true;
        disableControls();

        //Wait for a button to be pressed in prompt1
        //Make an action based on a button pressed.
        //closeApp returns a boolean

        if (!prompt1.closeApp)
        {
            prompt1.Visible = false;
            prompt1.Enabled = false;
            enableControls();
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

}
```

Here's my code at the prompt object:

```
public partial class Prompt : UserControl
{
    bool exit;

    public bool closeApp
    {
        get{return exit;}
    }

    public Prompt()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_yes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        exit = true;
    }

    private void btn_no_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        exit = false;
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

What I want to do is wait for a button to be pressed in my prompt object before proceeding to the next line in the btn_close_Click().

What should I do? Is there a better way to implement this?

Comment: why don't you use another form instead of using an hidden control

Comment: I tried making a form, but it is also hard to make that form communicate with my main form. I can do it, but it wont disable my components in the main form.

Comment: You easily can use a `MessageBox`. Or if you need a custom dialog, show the form using `ShowDialog`. For each button, you can set the `DialogResult` to `Yes`, `No`,`OK`, `Cancel`. And you can check the result of `ShowDialog`.

Comment: You should show the form as a dialog using form.showdialog.this will disable the controls on your main form till the second form is closed

Answer (score 1):

Add events to your usercontrol then handle those events on your main form.

In your usercontrol:

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> ExitCancelled;
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> ExitApplication;

private void btn_yes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ExitApplication?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}

private void btn_no_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ExitCancelled?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Handle the events on your form:

```
public void prompt1_ExitApplication(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Exit();
}

public void prompt1_ExitCancelled(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    prompt1.Hide();
    enablecontrols();
}
```